# Peer-to-peer UDP collaborative syncing possible?

Tags: networking

I'm developing an Android application where they want to have track multiple patient's vitals (current HR, SPO2, Respiration, etc.) in real-time with each patient having a large form that represents their documentation. They want this to be sent over a peer-to-peer UDP network, so that other people can edit the same documentation on the app on the same local network. They want people to be able to drop in and out of the network too. Lastly they want people to be able to collaborate without syncing issues.

Despite my push for a central server on the local network and/or TCP, they won't let me do it because of the process of setting up the server that would be up to the users.

Since I can't send the entire state of a client, I figured I would have to send commands that represent changes that each client makes then broadcast them to all other clients on the network. I'm not too sure how I would handle a packet being dropped and causing clients to be out of sync. I have heard about peer-to-peer lockstep, but not too sure if it's the right approach.

Is there a feasible approach to such a complex problem?

Comment: How is peer-to-peer lockstep relevant here?

Comment: I sure hope your contact has a clause indemnifying you against being held responsible for harm caused by the raft of ways in which this could fail.

Comment: I think the people giving you requirements have no idea what they're talking about.  Ask them for use cases without terms like 'UDP' and 'peer to peer'.  Those are implementation details, not requirements.

Comment: Also, peer-to-peer does not imply UDP.  Peer-to-peer is a system architecture, UDP is a communication protocol.  You can design a peer-to-peer system where the peers communicate over TCP.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I'm very new to networking and this job is pretty weird and interesting at the same time. It's prototyping ideas that are really out of the norm because the customers (military) and my boss (who has a Phd in computer engineering) have a lack of knowledge of what is feasible in software. Such as stuffing full pages of documentation into multiple QR codes...I cringe.. a lot. This is why I'm asking about this because I'm tired of doing things that are completely crazy because I don't know what is - and in the end it becomes stressful when it doesn't work.

Comment: In that case do feasibility studies.  Educate them, show them the limits, and explore the possibilities. As for the stress, manage their expectations of what you can investigate within  your time limits.

Comment: So much more constructive communication can happen when you have a straw man to dress.  I guarantee there are things in your senior engineer's mind that aren't in yours.  Having something concrete to demonstrate your thinking can help them help you--or change directions.

Comment: see [Why is "Is it possible to:" a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Answer (score 1):

I think your fundamental problem here is that you are mixing up user requirements, architecture design, and implementation details in one big lump:

- Android application [user requirement]
- track multiple patient's vitals (current HR, SPO2, Respiration, etc.) [user requirement]
- in real-time [user requirement]
- each patient having a large form that represents their documentation. [user requirement]
- peer-to-peer [architecture]
- UDP [implementation]
- so that other people can edit the same documentation on the app on the same local network. [user requirement]
- They want people to be able to drop in and out of the network too. [user requirement]
- collaborate without syncing issues [requirement]
- process of setting up the server that would be up to the users [user requirement]

Nothing labelled [user requirement] forces a peer to peer architecture nor a UDP implementation.

In fact, several of the requirements make it extremely difficult to implement with a peer to peer architecture and UDP implementation.  Synchronizing data across multiple users requires a master copy to be held by someone.  It sounds like data integrity would be a requirement here, and UDP does not guarantee data transmission.

I think you need to back up and gather a list of user requirements that don't dive into architecture or implementation details.  Then design an architecture from that.

Answer (score 0):

There's some real problems with this.

- Whose state is authoritative? Two people change a piece of data, who is right? With no central repo and async messaging, how do you decide who even came first?
- How do you recover from lost packets? Are you going to reinvent TCP?
- What about authentication and privacy? Will every device just trust every other one? That's going to come bite you if you ever manage to solve the other problems.

Comment: There's no authoritative, that's a big problem I'm noticing. I don't want to reinvent TCP in order to recover lost packets, and will need to tell them no if comes to that. Every device will know everything about each other. They don't care about privacy since it will be tested over a local network with people interacting with each other in the same room.

Comment: @Ateh why would it even be a requirement to use UDP? That should be a technical decision. The other things I mentioned are also difficult. Better think about whether to go ahead with this project.